# cor function giving different values when attributes passed individually and when passed in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation

I am trying to use the cor() function to find correlation between different attributes in a dataframe. When I pass attributes individually like in:

```
cor_or1_or7 = cor(plant_data$Orientation1, plant_data$Orientation7, 
                  method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs")
```

I get the correlation between plant_data$Orientation1 and plant_data$Orientation7 to be -0.8696721

But when I pass the whole dataframe, that contains all the attributes, I get a value of -0.89070093 for the same pair of attributes.

The code I used for passing the entire dataframe into the cor() function:

```
correlation_table <- cor(plant_data[2:19], method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs")
```

There are in total of 18 attributes with 724 instances in the dataframe.

I can't seem to figure out why the same function, applied to the same set of values is giving different answers! Can anyone please tell me what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example? I checked with `mtcars`, and I don't face this problem. But one possibility may be that `complete.obs` checks for the full dataframe in 2nd case, and only for the pair in 1st case.

Answer (score 0):

This will be because using the `complete.obs` argument, depending on where your NAs fall in other variables in columns 2-19, the sample will change. Say you have the entire data set for Orientation 1 and Orientation 7, n = 50 for example, then all 50 data points are used in the correlation calculation calling just those two variables. If in another variables you have 3 NAs and n = 47, by calling the whole data frame you will n = 47 data points for all variables before calculating the correlation coefficient and so the value for Orientation 1 and 7 will change.